# Agent is giving a non zero value(-126) as a status in catalina MacOS

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am facing an issue when i start my agent using command ./svc.sh start. Agent is starting but it is giving a non zero status(-126) and i am not able to run this as a service.Please help me on this.

Below steps followed.

1. Downloaded  vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.160.1  for mac and kept in agent folder.
2. Run (./config.sh) from terminal
3. Entered Azure DevOps url and PAT token with limited access(Scope 
      enabled for agent pool(Read&Manage) and packaging(Read)).
4. Run command ./svc.sh install
5. updated runsvc.sh file with android and java environment 
      variable.
6. run command ./svc.sh start and Agent started.

   After above steps when i was checking from DevOps, observed that agent is still offline.So again tried command ./svc.sh status from terminal.It is giving a non zero value(-126).

   Note: I am using MacOs(Catalina 10.15.1)

Comment: Hi friend, sorry but I can't reproduce same issue in my machine. Do you get any warning when configuring the agent? And what's the result if you delete the myagent folder and do as what document suggests again? (1.mkdir myagent && cd myagent 2. tar zxvf ~/Downloads/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.160.1.tar.gz 3. ./config.sh 4. ./svc.sh install 5../svc.sh start )

Comment: I am having the same issue. This began yesterday after some Mac OS system updates. The agent stopped communicating with DevOps and I went to reconfigure the agent as instructed. The agent reports that it is configured correctly but it always shows as offline in the agent pool.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's something wrong with the process when you configure the mac self agent.

You can follow my steps below to remove the registered agent and start it again:

1.Navigate to the myagent folder(cd ~/myagent$) and run `./svc.sh stop` and `./svc.sh uninstall`

2.Run `./config.sh remove` to remove the agent, delete the myagent folder manually if it exists

3.Open terminal to run `mkdir myagent` and `cd myagent` one by one

4.Run `tar zxvf ~/Downloads/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.160.1.tar.gz`

5.Run `./config.sh`, enter the Azure Devops URL and then Enter(choose using PAT)+PAT(Try using PAT with Full access)+Enter

6.After that, run `./svc.sh install` and then `./svc.sh start`. Please follow this order to get it work, avoid running `./run.sh` in any of above step. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Lance Li. Few informations updated in my initial post which i missed to add first time. 
 Meanwhile tried above solution as well, again got same result(-126) and still agent shows offline.Please let me know if any update on this.

Comment: @Lijo You're welcome! Does this issue still exist to block you? If there's any update feel free to let us know:)

Comment: Yes, still this issue exist

Comment: @Lijo Hi, I checked with one engineer who's more experienced in this topic. As he said, 126 indicates that it has no access to do something, could you please share a screen about the error window in your question so that we can check it directly. (Note: Pay attention to protect the personal data like name, email,... in screenshot)

Comment: Pleas see this link for screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD0rz.png

Comment: @Lijo Got it, thanks for the info. I'm now trying to involve some more experienced in this topic to help. It may take some time. Hope it helps :)

Comment: sure, Thanks Lance Li

Comment: Hi Lance Li, Can you please provide an update on this issue.

Comment: @Lijo Sorry for the delay. Have you updated Mac OS system before you get that strange issue? Like what **Grahambo** commented in your answer below? Mac Update may cause some changes for some OS permissions, and that's what 126 code means. Also, the document about self-agent in Mac has updated in 2020, please follow [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with) to make sure your organization works with existing firewall or IP restrictions.